# Statistics - which distributions fit the description

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I need to determine (then sample from) two distribution $X$ and $Y$, which have the following requirements:

- $X$ has 15k samples, $Y$ has 20k
- $X$ has a mean of 6k, $Y$ has a mean of 4k
- $X$ and $Y$ have the same median
- $X$ IQR is smaller than $Y$ IQR

Which distributions can meet these requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course many distributions would fit. I guess it's easy to check our work for discrete random variables:

\begin{align*}
X &= 6000 \\
Y &= \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 6000 & \text{with probability 0.6} \\ 1000 & \text{with probability 0.4}\end{array}\right.
\end{align*}